# How to change the line stroke for an array of line elements in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I would like to change the stroke color on a grid of lines over a grid element.  I get the following error message:

Error   CS0123  No overload for 'BtnClk' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler'

Here's a snippet of the code I have so far:

MainWindow.xaml:

```xml
<StackPanel
    x:Name="s"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center">

    <Button
        x:Name="b"
        Content="Change line color..."
        Click="BtnClk">
    </Button>
    <Line
        x:Name="ln1"
        X1="50"
        X2="50"
        Y1="50"
        Y2="500"
        Stroke="Blue">
    </Line>
    
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static SolidColorBrush _stroke;
     
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnClk(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        foreach (FrameworkElement Framework_Element in s.Children)
        {
            ((Line)Framework_Element).Stroke = _stroke;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's another version of the same I tried before narrowing it down to the above:

On this second version I get the following error:

Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MainWindow.s'

Any ideas on how to get either of these methods working?

MainWindow.xaml:

```xml
<StackPanel
    x:Name="s"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center">

    <Button
        x:Name="b"
        Content="Change line color..."
        Click="BtnClk">
    </Button>
    <Line
        x:Name="ln1"
        X1="50"
        X2="50"
        Y1="50"
        Y2="500"
        Stroke="{x:Bind RT_Stroke, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </Line>
    
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static SolidColorBrush _stroke;
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        RT_Stroke = new StrokeUpdate();
    }

    private StrokeUpdate RT_Stroke { get; set; }

    private void BtnClk(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        NotifyPropertyChanged();

        void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    } 

    public class StrokeUpdate
    {
        public void StrokeLoader(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (FrameworkElement Framework_Element in s.Children)
            {
                ((Line)Framework_Element).Stroke = _stroke;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I would like to change the stroke color on a grid of lines over a grid element.* Could you please provide more description? Or Could you describe what you want to do?

Comment: I have a grid of two arrays of line elements overlayed perpendicularly to form a horizontal and vertical array of grid lines across a canvas.  I'm trying to get the line colors changed for all lines located within the 'Grid' element that contains them by the push of one button at a time.  I hope to add a color picker with a set of color buttons which would allow the user to change the color of the lines in the grid.

Comment: The part of changing line color has been answered by @AndrewKeepCoding. If I understand you correctly, the concept of *Grid* need considering specially, for example [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juwXi.png).

Answer (score 1):

The first sample code compiles on my side.

The second sample of code doesn't compile because the `StackPanel` "s" cannot be accessed from the nested class **StrokeUpdate**.

If you just need to change the color by clicking the button:

```xml
<Button
    x:Name="b"
    Click="BtnClk"
    Content="Change line color..." />
<Line
    x:Name="ln1"
    Stroke="Red"
    X1="50"
    X2="50"
    Y1="50"
    Y2="500" />
```

```cs
private void BtnClk(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ln1.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
}
```

**UPDATE**

In the comments, you mentioned that you want to change the color of the `Line`s in a `Grid`. You can try this way:

```cs
private void SetLinesStroke(Grid grid, Brush foreground)
{
    foreach (Line line in grid.Children.OfType<Line>())
    {
        line.Stroke = foreground;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```cs
SetLinesStroke(someGrid, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White));
```

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the info, it worked!  I revised it to the following:                              public void btn1Clk(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Line line in g.Children.OfType<Line>())
    {
        line.Stroke = r1.Fill;
    }
}

Comment: Glad it helped. If this answer was helpful, please accept it as the answer so we can close this session.

Comment: @jv1597 Could you please mark answer for completion of the question?

Comment: The code you suggested worked really well.  We can close this issue now.  Thanks again.